# Winforms - how to show extra fields of an item on a form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am trying to create a form for collecting information about an item. There are two types: default item and special item. The fields of item shows on the form by default.

```
public class Item
{
   Id
   Name
   Quantity
   Type //default, special
}

public class SpecialItem : Item //inherits from item
{
   //extra fields here
   ExpiryDate
   SafeForChildren
}
```

How will I take the extra fields of SpecialItem to user.

I think the fields of SpecialItem should not show until the user indicates he wants to add special item by selecting the type.

I think of using a tab to show extra fields
A collapsible control - I don't if this exists
Hiding the controls and showing them when necessary
Any other idea

Comment: What are the specific property return types (e.g. some kind of enum for Type?) and form control types you are using for the default Item properties? It would be easy enough to design your form with a TableLayoutPanel with the rows for the special fields set to AutoSize; then you could just set the controls associated with each special property to `Visible = false`. Everything else will flow properly.

Comment: something like that... i plan to have a dropdown where you select the type and the right extra fields would show. but Winforms do they grow?

Comment: Yes. Using a TableLayoutPanel with rows set to AutoSize will use only as much space as is needed. If the contents are invisible, everything below it in the table will move up to fill in the empty space; when the controls are shown, the table will reflow with the additional fields inserted in the proper location. It's very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two class have a clear relation between them and this relation is well comprensible to your user, I think it's a good thing to show every field.
Put all the fields inside a groupbox and add two option buttons for the Item and SpecialItem class.
By default (at form load) the Item class will be selected and the two extra field are disabled.
If the user choose the SpecialItem class option button, enable the other two fields.

I have seen this behavior in many options dialogs when selecting an option will enable other specific options.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out - it simply reflects the given type and then puts the controls onto a `TableLayoutPanel` adds a couple of buttons and then binds two event handlers to the click event of the buttons. It is by no means a masterpeice, but I think will get you started.

```
public MyForm(Type typeToDisplay)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PropertyInfo[] settableProperties = typeToDisplay.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

            TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
            panel.ColumnCount = 2;
            panel.RowCount = settableProperties.Length+1;
            panel.Name = "LayoutPanel";
            this.Controls.Add(panel);

            int rowIndex = 0;

            foreach (PropertyInfo info in settableProperties)
            {
                Label propLabel = new Label();
                propLabel.Text = info.Name;

                TextBox propField = new TextBox();

                panel.Controls.Add(propLabel, 0, rowIndex);
                panel.Controls.Add(propField, 1, rowIndex);

                rowIndex++;
            }

            panel.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "OK", Name="OK" }, 0, rowIndex);
            panel.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "Cancel", Name="Cancel" }, 1, rowIndex);

            panel.Controls["Cancel"].Click += new EventHandler(CloseForm);
            panel.Controls["OK"].Click += new EventHandler(SaveChanges);

            panel.Height = this.Height;
            panel.Width = this.Width;

        }

        private void CloseForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void SaveChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Save changes was clicked!");
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, if the type is known when the form is built. It doesn't provide for switching the selected item type based on one of the properties on the form itself, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example solution to demonstrate my suggestion above. Note that it is all done in code and uses only a single column, but can work with designer-produced controls (of course) and multiple columns, too. Just be sure to set all the controls in a row (say, a label and its corresponding input control) to `Visible = false` to have the unused rows collapse properly.

```
TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 25));
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 25));
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 25));
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 25));
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 25));

TextBox b1 = new TextBox(); b1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
TextBox b2 = new TextBox(); b2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
TextBox b3 = new TextBox(); b3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
CheckBox special = new CheckBox(); special.Text = "Special?";
TextBox b4 = new TextBox(); b4.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; b4.Visible = false;
TextBox b5 = new TextBox(); b5.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; b5.Visible = false;
Button button = new Button(); button.Text = "Save";

special.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler((sender, args) => { b4.Visible = b5.Visible = special.Checked; });

tlp.Controls.Add(b1, 0, 0);
tlp.Controls.Add(b2, 0, 1);
tlp.Controls.Add(b3, 0, 2);
tlp.Controls.Add(special, 0, 3);
tlp.Controls.Add(b4, 0, 4);
tlp.Controls.Add(b5, 0, 5);
tlp.Controls.Add(button, 0, 6);

Controls.Add(tlp);
tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tlp.BringToFront();
```